# Adjust width and placement of NSSegmentedControl with dynamic in toolbar

Tags: cocoa, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem, nssegmentedcontrol

I've got a pretty dynamic UI that uses a `NSSegmentedControl` in the toolbar of its document window.

The `NSSegmentedControl` dynamically gets its elements assigned.

The number of elements can vary widely between 1 and maybe 15.

At the moment the toolbar will not adjust for the number of elements in the `NSSegmentedControl`, i.e. after setting the number of segments via `setSegmentCount:` all segments that exceed the original width of the `NSSegmentedControl` (at the time the window was created) are clipped:

[image]

What would be the best way to tell the `NSToolbar` to recalculate the width of all its elements, i.e. the width of the `NSSegmentedControl` and the placements of all elements right to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clipping is caused by `NSToolbarItem`'s current value for `-maxSize`. Try adjusting its width with `- setMaxSize:` after you add segments to the `NSSegmentedControl` or directly set the maximal width in Interface Builder.

There is more info on this topic at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Toolbars/Tasks/SettingTBItemSize.html